# Argument not optional Issue

Tags: excel, vba

This error is encountered, while running a macro in Excel??

Showing the Highlighted Error

[image]

```
Sub MoveBtn()
 With Sheet1
   .Range("E5").Validation.Delete
 If Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = "Purchase" Then
     .Shapes("MoveBtn1").IncrementLeft 30 'NOTE: there must be a space between "IncrementLeft" and "30"
     .Range("B1").Value = "Sales"
     .Range("E5").Validation.Add xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Customers"
Else:
 .Shapes("MoveBtn1").IncrementLeft -30 'NOTE: there must be a space between "IncrementLeft" and "-30"
     .Range("B1").Value = "Purchase"
     On Error Resume Next
      .Range("E5").Validation.Add
     .Range("E5").Validation.Add xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Vendors"
End If
 If .Range("B3").Value = False And .Range("B2").Value <> Empty Then .Range("D" & .Range("B2").Value).Value = .Range("B1").Value 'Set Trans Type
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that line as the next line is the needed one. The complaint is because that line doesn't have the one required param

```
expression.Add (Type, AlertStyle, Operator, Formula1, Formula2)
```

`Type` is required.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.add

Comment: Yeah I got That Thanks @QHarr For you time.